# Module '"@angular/material"' has no exported member 'MatFormFieldModule'

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am going to use `MatFormFieldModule` in Angular 12.

I imported this module from `@angular/material` and `@NgModule` like below:

```
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material';


@NgModule({
....

imports: [
  MatFormFieldModule,
  ...
  ],
...

})
```

And used this `MatFormFieldModule` in html file

```
<mat-form-field>
  ...
</mat-form-field>
```

But I got the error like this:

```
Error: src/app/app.module.ts:9:3 - error TS2305: Module '"@angular/material"' has no exported member 'MatFormFieldModule'.

9   MatFormFieldModule
```

Not sure about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check [the documentation for the material form field](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api) you can notice that the right import path for the `MatFormFieldModule` is `@angular/material/form-field`. Please try this:

```
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
```

Comment: so do i have to add `form-field` at the end of material link?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You need to use the correct import path